# How to Access public static variable of a instantiated object from another script in Unity using GetComponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

I have a unity C# script that has Some "Public static Variables" as shown below. This script is attached to the instantiated object.

```
public class PlaceAtLocation : MonoBehaviour
    {
         public static double Longitude, Latitude;
    }
```

I want to access these static variables "Latitude" and "Longitude" in another script. That is shown below

```
public class Instansiate_object : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject GpsStageObject;
  public GameObject tempbject;

  public void InstansiateGpSStageObject()
    {
      
       tempbject= Instantiate(GpsStageObject, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        tempbject.GetComponent<PlaceAtLocation>().lat =1;
        tempbject.GetComponent<PlaceAtLocation>().lon =1;
        //I want to access latitude and longitude here
        //=============================================
        //tempbject.GetComponent<PlaceAtLocation>().Longitude =1;
        //tempbject.GetComponent<PlaceAtLocation>().Latitude =1;
        //============================================= 
        
       print("Instansiated");
      
        

    }

}
```

Comment: `PlaceAtLocation.Longitude = 1;`

Comment: if it is [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) you do not go through any instance at all ... it belong directly to the type `PlaceAtLocation` and doesn't know about any instances

Comment: If multiple objects were instantiated, this will work or not

Comment: @Savad depends what `work` means ... they will all *share* the same `static` value ... Why do you think it does need to be `static`

Comment: You might want to rethink your design, a `PlaceAtLocation` with `static` coordinates makes little sense if the aim is to let users specify the location in the Editor.

Answer (score -1):

try using this format

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class YetAnotherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numberOfPlayerDeaths = 3;
}


using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class UsingOtherComponents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject otherGameObject;
    private YetAnotherScript yetAnotherScript;
    
    
    void Awake ()
    {
        
        yetAnotherScript = otherGameObject.GetComponent<YetAnotherScript>();
    }
    
    
    void Start ()
    {
        Debug.Log("The player has died " + yetAnotherScript.numberOfPlayerDeaths + " times");
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as I can tell from OP's code snippet OP was already trying exactly that ... OP's field is `static` though